# Java subclass constructor from superclass

Tags: java, android, subclass

I am trying to intercept the `onDraw()` method of the Android `android.view.View` class, to have a clue about when the view has finished to draw itself (and subsequently launch other operations).

However, this conducted me to some Java questions (I have limited experience with Java).

My Activity `onCreate()` method contains the following code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nessiean, null);
setContentView(view);
doSomeOperations();
```

I defined a subclass, whose main purpose is to define an internal state and provide a `wait()` method:

```
class MyView extends View{
    int state=0;

    public MyView(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context,attrs);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context,attrs,defStyle);
    }

    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        state=1;
    }

    public void waitforDraw(){
        while(state==0){};
    }
}
```

Questions are:

1. do I need to re-define all the public constructors in my subclass, as above? Java does not call them by default?
2. I cannot replace in my `onCreate()` method the line:

`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nessiean, null);`

with

`MyView view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nessiean, null);`

The error being: `cannot convert from View to MyView`.

Any hints?

==========================FULL CODE FOLLOWS==============================

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

public class SoundActivity extends Activity {

    private Thread mWorkerThread;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //START: ALTERNATIVE WAY FOR CREATING THE VIEW
        //*first variant:
        //setContentView(R.layout.nessiean);
        //*second variant:
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        MyView view = (MyView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.nessiean, null);
        setContentView(view);
        //STOP: ALTERNATIVE WAY FOR CREATING THE VIEW
        System.loadLibrary("soundtest");
        mWorkerThread =  new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                execute();      
            }
        },"Worker Thread");
        try{
            mWorkerThread.start();
            mWorkerThread.join(); 
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.exit(1); 
        }
    }   

    private native void execute();
}

class MyView extends View{
    int state=0;

    public MyView(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context,attrs);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context,attrs,defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        state=1;
    }

    public void waitforDraw(){
        while(state==0){};
    }
}
```

Comment: see my edits.. that might help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> do I need to re-define all the public constructors in my subclass, as above?

It depends - do you want to have all those constructors? Only declare the ones that *your* class needs.

> Java does not call them by default?

No. If you don't declare *any* constructors, the compiler will attempt to create one for you of the form:

```
public ClassName() {
    super();
}
```

For any declared constructor, if you don't explicitly chain to another constructor (either in the superclass or this class) it will implicitly add `super()` - i.e. a call to the parameterless constructor in the superclass. If that constructor doesn't exist or is inaccessible, you'll get a compile-time failure.

> I cannot replace in my onCreate() method the line:
>
> ```
> View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nessiean, null);
> ```
>
> with
>
> ```
> MyView view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nessiean, null);
> ```

If the call to `inflate` will *actually* return an instance of `MyView`, then you can just add a cast:

```
MyView view = (MyView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.nessiean, null);
```

I don't know enough about the inflater to say for sure whether that will work.

Comment: its hard to imagine you typed this much in such a short time..:)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. If I define no constructor (I do not need any), then I receive: "Implicit super constructor View() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor". The second problem is that inflater.inflate() actually returns a View (not MyView) object. However, I would like somehow pick that View object, convert it into a MyView object (so that I have the hack on onDraw()) and, finally, feed the new MyView object to the setContentView() method (which accepts View objects).

Comment: @sandy: Well some of it was quoting - so cut and paste helped there :)

Comment: @axeoth .. You atleast need 1 constructor of its parent class if you ever want to use it... and if you have your contructor you probably know it must invoke the super contructor... And you don't have to inflate a view when you can just add your **MyView** using **addView()**

Comment: @sandy: thank you. You seem be at ease with Android, can you, please, detail a bit the use of addView() in this context? I have a layout defined in my AndroidManifest.xml and all that I want is to be sure it was displayed (for good) on the screen before launching my workthread.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, if you want to call the super class constructor as shown.  It's necessary.
2. Try casting the `View` returned from inflate to `MyView`.

Comment: Thank you. It works that way (see my comments above), but I fear that the method setMyContentView(), inherited, originally accepting View objects, does not really understand the MyView object that I'm passing to it. It "compiles", but it crashes on the JVM.

Comment: An instance of MyView IS-A View.  If it crashes in the JVM at runtime, it suggests that your implementation fails to satisfy the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: I will dig further. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your nessiean.xml file, instead of declaring `<View>...</View>`, you need to simply chagne it to <`MyView>...</MyView>`. This way you are actually returning a MyView object when you call findViewById

Also, your onCreate method should just be:

```
setContentView(R.layout.nessiean);
MyView myView = (MyView) findViewById(R.id.<whatever tag you gave the view);
```